# Apache Iceberg on Redshift Spectrum, is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum, apache-iceberg

I have seen here https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-redshift-spectrum-adds-support-for-querying-open-source-apache-hudi-and-delta-lake/ that Redshift Spectrum has support for Hudi and Delta.

We're using Iceberg right now as a file format, and we have the requirement to read some tables externally in redshift spectrum for the BI Team.
I have created an external schema and an external table, but when I try to read the table, Redshift spectrum gives me more data then we should.

We are inserting data based in primary key, so what happens in redshift spectrum the way I tried is that it returns me all records for the same id, instead of returning me only the latest version of it (like a partition by id).

Has anyone tried with success to integrate Iceberg with AWS Redshift Spectrum?

Answer (score 0):

It was asked by me before if Apache Iceberg could be queried through redshift spectrum,
AWS from 2023 july an on supports querying Apache Iceberg Format through redshift spectrum - documentation can be found below:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/amazon-redshift-querying-apache-iceberg-tables/
So yes, it is possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).